# Beautiful Soup django parsing

Tags: django, beautifulsoup

I need to get data/string from XML file with tag description. I have:

`<description>&lt;img src="https://www.somepicture.jpeg" align="left" hspace="8" width="400" height="200" /&gt; DESCRIPTION TEXT I WANT TO PARSE </description>`

Im using BeautifoulSoup4 and Django, also, previous I made new soup from which I parse one item. If I try "item.description.text" I'm also getting this img tag.
How can I escape it, and get just desired description?

Edit: need to save this parsed text in database. Like:

```
for item in items: 
  tagA = item.tagA.text
  tagB = item.tagB.text
  description = item.description.text  <--- here's parsed text that I need without img tag
  model = MyModel.objects.create(tag_a_field=tagA, tag_b_field=tagB, description_field=description)
  model.save()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the `img` part is intended to be text. It is part of the description and that's why BeautifulSoup doesn't parse it as an html tag.

A naive approach to solve you problem is to parse that text again:

```
html = '<description>&lt;img src="https://www.somepicture.jpeg" align="left" hspace="8" width="400" height="200" /&gt; DESCRIPTION TEXT I WANT TO PARSE </description>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
description_soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.description.text)
description_soup.text
>>> ' DESCRIPTION TEXT I WANT TO PARSE '
```

In your case (according to the few information provided) you could write something like:

```
for item in items:
    tagA = item.tagA.text
    tagB = item.tagB.text
    description_soup = BeautifulSoup(item.description.text)
    description = description_soup.text
    MyModel.objects.create(tag_a_field=tagA, tag_b_field=tagB, description_field=description)
```

Comment: That's first thing I thought to do, but problem is that I need to make it dynamic. I'm itereting through previous soup and saving text from other tags in models. As you suggested if i put "html = item.description" then I'll get that object is not callable

Comment: I am not sure I understand, can you clarify in your original question, maybe with an example?

Comment: made it, hope It'll help

Comment: I don't think that that's your actual code. The `model.save()` part can't work since you are calling it on the class, and not an instance of the class.
It is very unclear what you are trying to do and what the problem with my solution is in your case, but I'll try to update my answer to provide a solution.

Comment: Thank you man, It works :) You were right, that was simplified version of code, ofc  I'm making instances of class. Sorry for misunderstanding and thank you once again.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. Maybe you can update the `model` part in your question to make it easier to understand for future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = '<description>&lt;img src="https://www.somepicture.jpeg" align="left" hspace="8" width="400" height="200" /&gt; DESCRIPTION TEXT I WANT TO PARSE </description>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
inner_soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.description.text, 'html.parser')
print(inner_soup.img.next_sibling)
```